# UI interaction for a notify me button

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, animation, button

I'm trying to imitate a UI interaction from dribble but for some reason the animation is messy after I select the send option.

Please have a look at my pen to understand what I mean.
Thank you!

http://codepen.io/sofiyashakeel/pen/PWdxdb

This is what my code looks like on-click for the send button:

```
$(function() {
  $("#send").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("button").removeClass("onclic");

      $(".info").addClass("hidden");

      $("button").addClass("validate", callback);
    }, 1050);
  });
});
```

Comment: `The animation is messy after I select the send option` - That is very interpretive. What **exactly** do you expect to happen? Is it the white text that appears you want to appear somewhere else or something else? or should the text disappear sooner or not at all? or should it follow the animation?

Comment: I'm sorry about that! I need the white text that reads "send" to disappear when "thank you" comes up but it doesn't happen though I removed the respective class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your issue was that you used `button` instead of the `.button` class in most places which applies effects to all buttons on the page rather than just your button with the `.button` class.

In the CSS I change `button{...}` to `.button{}` and in your JS code I changed all references the to `button` to be `.button` which seems to have fixed it.

You example code would look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#send").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      //$("button").removeClass("onclic");
      $(".button").removeClass("onclic");

      $(".info").addClass("hidden");

      //$("button").addClass("validate", callback);
      $(".button").addClass("validate", callback);
    }, 1050);
  });
});
```

Couldn't get SCSS working in snippet so updated CodePen below.

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgaMwd)